# Storing data by using SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql

I am not too familiar using SQL for storing Android data items but below I have couple of methods to insert a new data item and to print all existing data.

My Flight class has the following attributes:

- Flight number - String
- airline - String
- date - String
- image path - String
- reg - String
- type - String ID
- int (unique to each instance)

For some reason I am not able to print my data, I am not sure if there is an issue with the `insertFlight()` method or `databaseToString()` method.

```
public class DatabaseSQ extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FlightDatabase.db";
    public static final String TABLE_FLIGHTS = "flights";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String FLIGHT_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String FLIGHT_NUMBER = "number";
    public static final String FLIGHT_DATE = "date";
    public static final String FLIGHT_REG = "reg";
    public static final String FLIGHT_AIRLINE = "airline";
    public static final String FLIGHT_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String FLIGHT_IMAGE_PATH = "image";

    public DatabaseSQ(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FLIGHTS + "(" +
            FLIGHT_COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                FLIGHT_NUMBER + " TEXT, " +
                FLIGHT_DATE + " TEXT, " +
                FLIGHT_REG + " TEXT, " +
                FLIGHT_AIRLINE + " TEXT, " +
                FLIGHT_TYPE + " TEXT, " +
                FLIGHT_IMAGE_PATH + " TEXT " +
                ");";

        db.execSQL(query);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FLIGHTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertFlight(Flight toADD) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(FLIGHT_COLUMN_ID, toADD.getId());
        contentValues.put(FLIGHT_NUMBER, toADD.getFlightNumber());
        contentValues.put(FLIGHT_DATE, toADD.getDate());
        contentValues.put(FLIGHT_REG, toADD.getReg());
        contentValues.put(FLIGHT_AIRLINE, toADD.getAirline());
        contentValues.put(FLIGHT_TYPE, toADD.getType());
        contentValues.put(FLIGHT_IMAGE_PATH, toADD.getImagePath());

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();




        db.insert(TABLE_FLIGHTS, null, contentValues);
        db.close();

    }

    public String databaseToString() {

        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FLIGHTS + " WHERE 1";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")) != null) {
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
}
```

This database is then called when in another activity file, when a button is clicked, a new flight object must be stored and its flight number be passed to the main activity. (Database object dbHandler is instantiated before).

```
public void AddFlight(View view) {

        String name = nameText.getText().toString();
        String date = dateText.getText().toString();
        String airline = airlineText.getText().toString();
        String type = typeText.getText().toString();
        String reg = regText.getText().toString();


        Context context = this;
        Class destination = MainActivity.class;

        Intent goBackToMain = new Intent(context, destination);


        Flight newFlight = new Flight(name, date, reg, airline, type, mCurrentPhotoPath);

        dbHandler.insertFlight(newFlight);

        String data = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        goBackToMain.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);

        startActivity(goBackToMain);
    }
```

Comment: Can you try to use  SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FLIGHTS  as your query? Please remove unnecessary " WHERE 1" part.

Comment: tried, didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are moving your cursor wrong on your table. Try as follow

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
if(c != null) {
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number"));
        dbString += "\n";
    }
    c.close()
}
```

Comment: I tried it and didn't work, i don't see much difference with that since i do move my cursor to the first row

Comment: What "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FLIGHTS + " WHERE 1" do? Something is wrong here! What `clausure where` need?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> FLIGHT_COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
> ```

You're missing a space between the column name and its type. That itself is not a syntax error, the column name just becomes `_idINTEGER`.

> ```
> contentValues.put(FLIGHT_COLUMN_ID, toADD.getId());
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> db.insert(TABLE_FLIGHTS, null, contentValues);
> ```

This insert will fail since there's no `FLIGHT_COLUMN_ID` column. Use `insertOrThrow()` rather than `insert()` to throw an exception on error.

Also you don't need to insert a value to an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column - a new rowid will be automatically generated for you.

After correcting the `CREATE TABLE` SQL, you can uninstall your app to make `onCreate()` run again.